# Projective cover of the trivial $\mathbb{k}G$ module $\mathbb{k}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

What I've been trying to understand is the projective cover of the trivial module $\mathbb{k}$ over the group algebra $\mathbb{k}G$, for $G$ a finite group and $\mathbb{k}$ some field of positive characteristic $p$. In that category, we know that the projective cover of a module always exists (and is unique up to isomorphism). But in practise, when want to write down that module then what do we have?

If someone notices the construction in the proof of it, then realises that this projective cover is nothing but the direct sum of the indecomposable projective modules, occurring in the decomposition of the module after has been factored out by its radical, which *by definition* is a sum of some simple modules. In the trivial case of (the trivial module) $\mathbb{k}$, one natural candidate for the projective cover, should be the group algebra $\mathbb{K}G$ itself along with the augmentation homomorphism. It is free $\mathbb{K}G$-module, hence projective and since $\mathbb{k}$ is simple it's just enough to prove that is indecomposable. How do we prove/disprove the latter though? Can you help me out? Also, if something doesn't make sense please do let me know!

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of editing it with something wrong, if $G$ is a $p$-group does the above have something to do with Nakayama's Lemma? Since in that case we have that the kernel is the radical of $\mathbb{K}G$, hence should be superfluous by the above lemma. So in this case the answer is positive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general $kG$ is not the projective cover because $kG$ will in general not be indecomposable. Remember that projective covers are always indecomposable.

Sadly, I don't think there is a nice, general, explicit form of the projective cover. (But I would be delighted if someone corrects me on this)

Regarding your comment: If $G$ is a $p$-group, then $kG$ is in fact local (because the augmentation ideal is spanned by nilpotent elements $g-1$) so that the augmentation map is indeed the projective cover of the trivial module $k$.

This has the useful consequence that the restriction $Res_S^G(P)$ of a projective $kG$-module to a sylow-$p$-subgroup $S\in Syl_p(G)$ is always a direct sum of copies of the regular $kS$-module. In particular: The character vanishes on $p$-elements and the dimension is a multiple of $|S|$.

Comment: In fact it can only be indecomposable when the group is a $p$-group. Otherwise one can take a subgroup of prime order $q\neq p$ and make an idempotent by taking the sum of its elements divided by $q$.

Comment: thank you for your clear answer

Comment: @user430191 I agree with this answer that there is probably no good description of the projective cover of the trivial module in general. In fact, I am fairly certain that for the special linear group over a finite field and working in the defining characteristic, we do not even know the dimension of it in general (though potentially one could work it out when the characteristic is large enough by using some work of Riche and Williamson together with some results in a recent paper of mine on how tilting modules split when restricted to this subgroup. But this would probably be hard).